# Best approach to add and remove elements from an html form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a simple html form with different inputs element. The questions and the possible choices for each question are stored in a database. The idea is to render form and child input elements with PHP, so a simple PHP function will take care of typesetting according to whether is `type="text"` or `type="radio"`:

```
<form>
First name: <input id="1" type="text" name="firstname">
Last name: <input id="2" type="text" name="lastname">
<input id="3" type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male
<input id="4" type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
<div id="div_5_optional">
Maiden name: <input id="5" type="text" name="maidenname" disabled="disabled">
</div>
</form>
```

Now, by default `input id="5"` will be disabled. But I also want to remove it. I am able to get it with JavaScript by loading in my header (although I can't guarantee the move to be smart)

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("[disabled=disabled]").parent().remove();
});
</script>
```

So far so good, the div element is removed. Yet, I want to put the element back and in the original position when the radio button corresponding to `Female` is clicked. I added in the header, just below the previous js script this

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/enable_elements.js'></script>
```

which loads this function

```
// enable_elements.js

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#4').click(function(){
    $( '#5' ).prop( "disabled", false );
    });

});
```

Yet the all thing doesn't work. I guess the problem could be the my `ready(function)`s are only loaded once at the beginning and then put to sleep? Should I structure my form differently?

Comment: Why are you removing the element if you would like to later add it back? Would it no make more sense to just hide it?  http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve, [you can do this with CSS](http://jsbin.com/jiqej/1/edit?html,css,output)...

Comment: ready function makes sure to load the functions after the DOM loaded. It will not put anything into sleep as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want to `remove()`, instead you want to `hide()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#5").hide();
});
```

Also you want to handle the click on `#3`:

```
$('#3').click(function(){
    $( '#5' ).attr("disabled", "disabled").hide();
});
$('#4').click(function(){
    $( '#5' ).attr("disabled", "").show();
});
```

Note: I kept the "disabled" attribute, but really you don't need it since it will be hidden when unselectable...

If you remove the `#5`, then it's lost and you cannot show it again. So clicking on Male, then Female, back on Male, and on Female again... would not work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a eventhandlers for the female and male checkbox that call your function and displays or hides the field